# How do i get the code formatter in Intellij to become stable

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting

We have a big project with lots of repos where we would like to introduce a coding standard that is followed in all repos.

We do this by adding an identical .editorconfig file in all repos.

When doing this we also format all java files by Code -> Reformat Code and filtering out *.java files.

I just noticed that this operation is not stable and intellij keeps toggling some code sections.

E.g. this code section ...

```
    public CaasOrder toggles(final String caasOrderId, final String authHeader) {
        final List<String> cardOrderIds = transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
            final Order order = getOrderWithInitiatedState(caasOrderId);
            final List<String> ids = order.getCardOrders().stream().map(CardOrder::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

            return ids;
        });
        return transactionTemplate.execute(s -> ObjectConverter.convert(getOrderWithInitiatedState(caasOrderId)));
    }
```

... keeps togling back and forth with this code section ...

```
    public CaasOrder toggles(final String caasOrderId, final String authHeader) {
        final List<String> cardOrderIds = transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
            final Order        order = getOrderWithInitiatedState(caasOrderId);
            final List<String> ids   = order
                    .getCardOrders()
                    .stream()
                    .map(CardOrder::getId)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return ids;
        });
        return transactionTemplate.execute(s -> ObjectConverter.convert(getOrderWithInitiatedState(caasOrderId)));
    }
```

This is really annoying and hinders us from enforcing a common coding standard in an easy way.

I.e. add our .editorconfig filen and reformat all java files and make a commit!

And here is the .editorconfig file

```
[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = crlf
indent_size = 4
indent_style = space
insert_final_newline = false
max_line_length = 120
tab_width = 4
ij_continuation_indent_size = 8
ij_formatter_off_tag = @formatter:off
ij_formatter_on_tag = @formatter:on
ij_formatter_tags_enabled = true
ij_smart_tabs = false
ij_visual_guides = none
ij_wrap_on_typing = false

[*.java]
ij_java_align_consecutive_assignments = false
ij_java_align_consecutive_variable_declarations = true
ij_java_align_group_field_declarations = true
ij_java_align_multiline_annotation_parameters = false
ij_java_align_multiline_array_initializer_expression = false
ij_java_align_multiline_assignment = false
ij_java_align_multiline_binary_operation = false
ij_java_align_multiline_chained_methods = false
ij_java_align_multiline_extends_list = false
ij_java_align_multiline_for = true
ij_java_align_multiline_method_parentheses = false
ij_java_align_multiline_parameters = true
ij_java_align_multiline_parameters_in_calls = false
ij_java_align_multiline_parenthesized_expression = false
ij_java_align_multiline_records = true
ij_java_align_multiline_resources = true
ij_java_align_multiline_ternary_operation = false
ij_java_align_multiline_text_blocks = false
ij_java_align_multiline_throws_list = false
ij_java_align_subsequent_simple_methods = false
ij_java_align_throws_keyword = false
ij_java_align_types_in_multi_catch = true
ij_java_annotation_parameter_wrap = off
ij_java_array_initializer_new_line_after_left_brace = false
ij_java_array_initializer_right_brace_on_new_line = false
ij_java_array_initializer_wrap = off
ij_java_assert_statement_colon_on_next_line = false
ij_java_assert_statement_wrap = off
ij_java_assignment_wrap = off
ij_java_binary_operation_sign_on_next_line = false
ij_java_binary_operation_wrap = off
ij_java_blank_lines_after_anonymous_class_header = 0
ij_java_blank_lines_after_class_header = 0
ij_java_blank_lines_after_imports = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_after_package = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_around_class = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_around_field = 0
ij_java_blank_lines_around_field_in_interface = 0
ij_java_blank_lines_around_initializer = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_around_method = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_around_method_in_interface = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_before_class_end = 0
ij_java_blank_lines_before_imports = 1
ij_java_blank_lines_before_method_body = 0
ij_java_blank_lines_before_package = 0
ij_java_block_brace_style = end_of_line
ij_java_block_comment_add_space = false
ij_java_block_comment_at_first_column = true
ij_java_builder_methods = none
ij_java_call_parameters_new_line_after_left_paren = false
ij_java_call_parameters_right_paren_on_new_line = false
ij_java_call_parameters_wrap = off
ij_java_case_statement_on_separate_line = true
ij_java_catch_on_new_line = false
ij_java_class_annotation_wrap = split_into_lines
ij_java_class_brace_style = end_of_line
ij_java_class_count_to_use_import_on_demand = 999
ij_java_class_names_in_javadoc = 1
ij_java_do_not_indent_top_level_class_members = false
ij_java_do_not_wrap_after_single_annotation = false
ij_java_do_not_wrap_after_single_annotation_in_parameter = false
ij_java_do_while_brace_force = never
ij_java_doc_add_blank_line_after_description = true
ij_java_doc_add_blank_line_after_param_comments = false
ij_java_doc_add_blank_line_after_return = false
ij_java_doc_add_p_tag_on_empty_lines = true
ij_java_doc_align_exception_comments = true
ij_java_doc_align_param_comments = true
ij_java_doc_do_not_wrap_if_one_line = false
ij_java_doc_enable_formatting = true
ij_java_doc_enable_leading_asterisks = true
ij_java_doc_indent_on_continuation = false
ij_java_doc_keep_empty_lines = true
ij_java_doc_keep_empty_parameter_tag = true
ij_java_doc_keep_empty_return_tag = true
ij_java_doc_keep_empty_throws_tag = true
ij_java_doc_keep_invalid_tags = true
ij_java_doc_param_description_on_new_line = false
ij_java_doc_preserve_line_breaks = false
ij_java_doc_use_throws_not_exception_tag = true
ij_java_else_on_new_line = false
ij_java_entity_dd_suffix = EJB
ij_java_entity_eb_suffix = Bean
ij_java_entity_hi_suffix = Home
ij_java_entity_lhi_prefix = Local
ij_java_entity_lhi_suffix = Home
ij_java_entity_li_prefix = Local
ij_java_entity_pk_class = java.lang.String
ij_java_entity_vo_suffix = VO
ij_java_enum_constants_wrap = off
ij_java_extends_keyword_wrap = off
ij_java_extends_list_wrap = off
ij_java_field_annotation_wrap = split_into_lines
ij_java_finally_on_new_line = false
ij_java_for_brace_force = never
ij_java_for_statement_new_line_after_left_paren = false
ij_java_for_statement_right_paren_on_new_line = false
ij_java_for_statement_wrap = off
ij_java_generate_final_locals = false
ij_java_generate_final_parameters = false
ij_java_if_brace_force = never
ij_java_imports_layout = *,|,javax.**,java.**,|,$*
ij_java_indent_case_from_switch = true
ij_java_insert_inner_class_imports = false
ij_java_insert_override_annotation = true
ij_java_keep_blank_lines_before_right_brace = 2
ij_java_keep_blank_lines_between_package_declaration_and_header = 2
ij_java_keep_blank_lines_in_code = 2
ij_java_keep_blank_lines_in_declarations = 2
ij_java_keep_builder_methods_indents = false
ij_java_keep_control_statement_in_one_line = true
ij_java_keep_first_column_comment = true
ij_java_keep_indents_on_empty_lines = false
ij_java_keep_line_breaks = false
ij_java_keep_multiple_expressions_in_one_line = false
ij_java_keep_simple_blocks_in_one_line = false
ij_java_keep_simple_classes_in_one_line = false
ij_java_keep_simple_lambdas_in_one_line = false
ij_java_keep_simple_methods_in_one_line = false
ij_java_label_indent_absolute = false
ij_java_label_indent_size = 0
ij_java_lambda_brace_style = end_of_line
ij_java_layout_static_imports_separately = true
ij_java_line_comment_add_space = false
ij_java_line_comment_add_space_on_reformat = false
ij_java_line_comment_at_first_column = true
ij_java_message_dd_suffix = EJB
ij_java_message_eb_suffix = Bean
ij_java_method_annotation_wrap = split_into_lines
ij_java_method_brace_style = end_of_line
ij_java_method_call_chain_wrap = on_every_item
ij_java_method_parameters_new_line_after_left_paren = false
ij_java_method_parameters_right_paren_on_new_line = false
ij_java_method_parameters_wrap = off
ij_java_modifier_list_wrap = false
ij_java_multi_catch_types_wrap = normal
ij_java_names_count_to_use_import_on_demand = 3
ij_java_new_line_after_lparen_in_annotation = false
ij_java_new_line_after_lparen_in_record_header = false
ij_java_packages_to_use_import_on_demand = java.awt.*,javax.swing.*
ij_java_parameter_annotation_wrap = off
ij_java_parentheses_expression_new_line_after_left_paren = false
ij_java_parentheses_expression_right_paren_on_new_line = false
ij_java_place_assignment_sign_on_next_line = false
ij_java_prefer_longer_names = true
ij_java_prefer_parameters_wrap = false
ij_java_record_components_wrap = normal
ij_java_repeat_synchronized = true
ij_java_replace_instanceof_and_cast = false
ij_java_replace_null_check = true
ij_java_replace_sum_lambda_with_method_ref = true
ij_java_resource_list_new_line_after_left_paren = false
ij_java_resource_list_right_paren_on_new_line = false
ij_java_resource_list_wrap = off
ij_java_rparen_on_new_line_in_annotation = false
ij_java_rparen_on_new_line_in_record_header = false
ij_java_session_dd_suffix = EJB
ij_java_session_eb_suffix = Bean
ij_java_session_hi_suffix = Home
ij_java_session_lhi_prefix = Local
ij_java_session_lhi_suffix = Home
ij_java_session_li_prefix = Local
ij_java_session_si_suffix = Service
ij_java_space_after_closing_angle_bracket_in_type_argument = false
ij_java_space_after_colon = true
ij_java_space_after_comma = true
ij_java_space_after_comma_in_type_arguments = true
ij_java_space_after_for_semicolon = true
ij_java_space_after_quest = true
ij_java_space_after_type_cast = true
ij_java_space_before_annotation_array_initializer_left_brace = false
ij_java_space_before_annotation_parameter_list = false
ij_java_space_before_array_initializer_left_brace = false
ij_java_space_before_catch_keyword = true
ij_java_space_before_catch_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_catch_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_before_class_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_colon = true
ij_java_space_before_colon_in_foreach = true
ij_java_space_before_comma = false
ij_java_space_before_do_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_else_keyword = true
ij_java_space_before_else_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_finally_keyword = true
ij_java_space_before_finally_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_for_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_for_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_before_for_semicolon = false
ij_java_space_before_if_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_if_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_before_method_call_parentheses = false
ij_java_space_before_method_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_method_parentheses = false
ij_java_space_before_opening_angle_bracket_in_type_parameter = false
ij_java_space_before_quest = true
ij_java_space_before_switch_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_switch_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_before_synchronized_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_synchronized_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_before_try_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_try_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_before_type_parameter_list = false
ij_java_space_before_while_keyword = true
ij_java_space_before_while_left_brace = true
ij_java_space_before_while_parentheses = true
ij_java_space_inside_one_line_enum_braces = false
ij_java_space_within_empty_array_initializer_braces = false
ij_java_space_within_empty_method_call_parentheses = false
ij_java_space_within_empty_method_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_around_additive_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_annotation_eq = true
ij_java_spaces_around_assignment_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_bitwise_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_equality_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_lambda_arrow = true
ij_java_spaces_around_logical_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_method_ref_dbl_colon = false
ij_java_spaces_around_multiplicative_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_relational_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_shift_operators = true
ij_java_spaces_around_type_bounds_in_type_parameters = true
ij_java_spaces_around_unary_operator = false
ij_java_spaces_within_angle_brackets = false
ij_java_spaces_within_annotation_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_array_initializer_braces = false
ij_java_spaces_within_braces = false
ij_java_spaces_within_brackets = false
ij_java_spaces_within_cast_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_catch_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_for_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_if_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_method_call_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_method_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_record_header = false
ij_java_spaces_within_switch_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_synchronized_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_try_parentheses = false
ij_java_spaces_within_while_parentheses = false
ij_java_special_else_if_treatment = true
ij_java_subclass_name_suffix = Impl
ij_java_ternary_operation_signs_on_next_line = false
ij_java_ternary_operation_wrap = off
ij_java_test_name_suffix = Test
ij_java_throws_keyword_wrap = off
ij_java_throws_list_wrap = off
ij_java_use_external_annotations = false
ij_java_use_fq_class_names = false
ij_java_use_relative_indents = false
ij_java_use_single_class_imports = true
ij_java_variable_annotation_wrap = off
ij_java_visibility = public
ij_java_while_brace_force = never
ij_java_while_on_new_line = false
ij_java_wrap_comments = false
ij_java_wrap_first_method_in_call_chain = true
ij_java_wrap_long_lines = true
wildcard_import_limit = 999

[.editorconfig]
ij_editorconfig_align_group_field_declarations = false
ij_editorconfig_space_after_colon = false
ij_editorconfig_space_after_comma = true
ij_editorconfig_space_before_colon = false
ij_editorconfig_space_before_comma = false
ij_editorconfig_spaces_around_assignment_operators = true
```

Comment: Does this happen on every save?

Comment: Yes! It toogles each time!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because there is two formattings going on - first you wrap at 120 (and one line is exactly 120 characters) it will wrap.

Then it will add the CRLF (as your config says).

Next time it looks at the line (*without thinking about CRLF*) and put's it   on one line and then add the CRLF.

This is ofcourse a bug in IntelliJ - so to work around you can set max_line_length to 122 to work around it.

If you don't want to change globally you can put an editorconfig file in the directory you have problem with.

Comment: Yea I guessed it had to do with that but to have to change the line length here and there is kind of not a solution. Jetbrains people please step in :-)

Comment: In the project where I am testing this it is cirka 25 files that is toggling each time.

Answer (score 1):

By changing the value of these two I finally got it to become stable.

```
ij_java_keep_line_breaks = true
ij_java_wrap_long_lines = false
```